# Invalid Parameter Number

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

What am I missing with this SUPER simple example where the code has initially been generated by Zend 2 SQL\Update however I've grabbed the SQL to process the error manually:

```
  $data = array(
      'Title' => 'Mrs'
  );

  $str = '`Title` = :Title';

  $this->adapter->query("UPDATE `contacts` SET $str WHERE `ContactID` = 5",$data);
```

This code has been working fine however have been updating columns etc and its suddenly stopped working but the above code looks like it should be fine?

Thanks

Antony

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 0):

At first look, change

```
$data = array(
    'Title' => 'Mrs'
);
```

to

```
$data = array(
    ':Title' => 'Mrs'
);
```

That being said, I wonder why

```
WHERE `ContactID` = 5
```

doesnt have another placeholder...

Comment: Please ignore this - I was being silly. need to exit my code after testing it!

Comment: Ok - booboo in code but problem still there and so investigating!

Comment: You said "have been updating columns etc and its suddenly stopped working", is the Title and ContactID columns still present in `contacts`  table?

What is the error output?

Comment: Ok - turns out the problem was I had a query using :2WeekReview as a parameter and it appears to not like the number! Change that and problem fixed. Very annoying though.